# Delete query for multiple tables

Tags: ms-access

How can I modify this code so that it will delete records from both tables that it gets the info from?

```
SELECT products_description.products_name, products.products_id
FROM products INNER JOIN products_description ON products.products_id =             products_description.products_id
WHERE (((products.products_ordered)=0) AND ((products.products_status)=0));
```

I'm very new to sql coding, so please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

Comment: obviously I'll have to change SELECT to DELETE, but it's asking to specify a table. How do I specify both?

Comment: have you put a relationship in between the tables. On delete cascade might do the job, but you need to havea think about what it will mean for you design. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/delete-one-or-more-records-from-an-access-database-HA001173951.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a relationship and a single query.

1. set a relationship between `products` and `products_description` based on the common field `products_id`
2. place a check mark in the box for "Enforce Referential Integrity"
3. place a check mark in the box for "Cascade Delete Related Records"
4. save the relationship

Then this query will delete rows from `products` and also any `products_description` rows which include `products_id` values matching those of the deleted `products` rows.

```sql
DELETE FROM products
WHERE
        products.products_ordered=0
    AND products.products_status=0;
```

If you go this route, please make sure you understand the consequences.  As an additional safeguard, make and test a backup of data you wish to keep.  ;-)

Comment: it doesn't let me check any of the options

Comment: Are both tables in the same database ... or is one a link to a table in a different database?  You can only enforce referential integrity between tables in the same database.

Comment: both in the same database yes

Comment: Then I don't understand why you're unable to create a relationship which enforces relational integrity between those 2 tables.  Is it only those 2 tables?  Can you create such a relationship between any other two tables in your db?

Comment: would it make a difference if the two tables weren't locally hosted by any chance? still both on the same db, but not local

Comment: I have the same issue and **both** tables are Linked Tables in another Access Database file. This likely means that the Relationship must be created within the linked database file, correct?

Comment: @4AM Yes, the relationship must be created in the database which contains the tables.

Comment: @HansUp Thanks, I was just coming back to state that I tried that and it worked. Looks like I will have more work cut out for me updating this tool I am working on...